# Restoring encrypted DB to SQL vNext

Tags: sql-server, linux, centos, always-encrypted

I wondered if anyone else may have tried restoring a copy of an encrypted database to an instance of SQL vNext. The instance I'm running has been installed on a CentOS box, but I'm not having any luck restoring this particular database, because I can't get my certs set up. I'm trying to follow the same practice that has allowed me to accomplish this on other instances/servers, to no avail. I've gone so far as to give full access (chmod 777) to most of the folders and files involved, because the error I'm receiving states that it may be a permissions issue. Everything that should be taking place would be in /var/opt/mssql/data, /var/opt/mssql/secrets, /var/opt/mssql/.

If any of you knowledgeable folks could point me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it. I will post more details/specific error message in the morning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be running into a bug in how SQL Server vNext CTP1.2 handles filepaths. To CREATE CERTIFICATE from a backup, you currently need to pre-pend a 'c:' and use backslashes ('\') instead of forward slashes. This will be fixed soon :)

Here's a demo for the scenario you're trying to do (backup an encrypted database and restore it on a SQL vNext on Linux instance). Let me know if it clarifies things for you.

https://github.com/tmullaney/tde-migration-demo

Comment: Thanks tmullaney, I finally got it. I appreciate the help, I think the biggest thing was getting it in the correct group and with the right permissions.